# In a firebase array how to search by value of one element?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase in Android. I have country name , cityname , latitude and longitude in the following structure.

[image]

I am trying to search based on name with the following code: for example Afghanisthan as country and just b as my search text.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://--------.firebaseio.com/latlangs");
Firebase childRef = ref.child("Afghanisthan");

Query queryRef = childRef.orderByChild("name").startAt("b").endAt("b"+"\uf8ff");
queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("=======dataSnapshot==============>"+dataSnapshot);
       
                       for (DataSnapshot keys : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      

       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
         System.out.println("=======error======>"+error);

       
    }
});
```

but the dataSnapshot is is empty like {key: AfganSthan: value: null}. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you have any records in the database, that start with (lower case) `b`? Can you show us an example?

Comment: @Alex Mamo I have tried with many letters. so you think the code is fine?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, but the `name` in your screenshot does not start with a `b` so will not be returned. What **data* do you expect to be returned by this when you search for `b`?

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the case sensetive nature of orderByChild query. I ended up modifying the call like the following and got fixed:

```
Query queryRef = childRef.orderByChild("name").startAt(capitalize(cityName)).endAt(capitalize(cityName) + "\uf8ff");
   


public static String capitalize(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.length() <= 1) return str;
        return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
    }
```